# Software to whitelist websites on a router

Tags: parental-control, website-blocker

Parental controls software does not block everything.  Now I feel like I need to whitelist websites exclusively.  I have a NetGear C3700 router.

I want to block websites from the router, not the desktop. It should be password protected.

Is there a solution I can get for free, or purchase if need be? I don't want to pay by month.

Comment: I have added an answer on how to whitelist and block IPs and Domain names, but this is not content-filtering. (I.E. You don't block `Porn`, you block the domain manually).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this may seem very vague (answer), it is intended to be viewed by others with different ISP (Internet Service Providers), and their equipment.

Depending on how you want to broach the subject (in terms of complexity) would determine how you implement this. My first suggestion is the use of [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/), which may or may not be supported on your [device](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start). From here we can use the [Netfilter](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/netfilter?s[]=filtering) options readily available.

**Note**: This method will require some knowledge of IP Tables and the CLI. For example, the following lines added will allow DNS requests incoming on a specific TCP Port:

```
root@openwrt:~# iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport  53 #------------------- accept incoming packets on tcp port 53 (DNS)
```

**DD-WRT** is a "fork" of OpenWRT and it is recommended to be implemented for users not as "Tech-Savy" as others. The following are examples of  how you could achieve this:

- [DD-WRT DNSMasq Setup and Local DNS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgfInxSbLX0)
- [DD-WRT: Blocking websites, games etc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbYUenvUkJQ).

For the sake of clarity, here are related links outlining **DD-WRT** vs. **OpenWRT** (they are different **firmwares**):

- [OpenWRT vs DDWRT](https://superuser.com/questions/316177/openwrt-vs-ddwrt)
- [DD-WRT vs OpenWRT vs Tomato: Which one is the best firmware for you?](https://mekachoice.com/technology/dd-wrt-vs-openwrt-vs-tomato-the-best-firmware/)

It is my recommendation, you should install a **secondary router** onto your LAN, and edit this; not the ISP stock-provided unit.

---

Now that OpenWRT and DD-WRT are highlighted, we can move onto other options available to you should you not want this.

[PiHole](https://pi-hole.net/):

> Network-wide ad blocking via your own Linux hardware

My recommendation might incur a requirement to operate a Raspberry Pi (and `SSH` to it). Essentially you make your router use the `Pi`'s IP Address as the DNS query, and from there you can block/poison DNS requests - commonly coined '[DNS Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing)'.

You can read up on [this Reddit Post about blocking sites](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/45xuh8/why_cant_i_watch_porn/) (this one relates to adult content), and even look at [this tool for editing your block list.](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/wiki/Customising-sources-for-ad-lists)

Comment: If you want to go down the PiHole route, here is a "Family Safe DNS Blocklist" you could use: https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/family-safe-dns-blocklist/85

Comment: If you prefer to get your hands dirty and do it yourself, here is a guide: https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-add-additional-block-lists-to-pi-hole/259/11

Answer (score 0):

Different ISPs have varying levels of parental control options right at your fingertips. For example, my ISP is xfinity. I can configure parental controls in the xFi app or by accessing the router directly by visiting http://10.0.0.1/. Find out how your ISP handles parental permissions by visiting there website.

Comment: "*Parental controls software does not block everything.*" was the first statement in this question.